# Web API change JSON parser

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I am trying to change the JSON parser in my web API project.

I have followed the following tutorials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNzgXjqqIjI

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/09/Using-an-alternate-JSON-Serializer-in-ASPNET-Web-API

I now have the following code:

```
public class MyJsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public MyJsonFormatter()
        {
            base.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            return base.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(type, request, mediaType);
        }

        public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override IRequiredMemberSelector RequiredMemberSelector { get => base.RequiredMemberSelector; set => base.RequiredMemberSelector = value; }
    }   



public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ///Other stuff...
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyJsonFormatter());          
}
```

My issue is that whatever I do, JSON gets parsed and it seems to ignore my code - I can throw exceptions in the read or write methods and nothing will happen, break points do not get hit etc.

I know this formatter is being added as only the content types in my class are visible and if I set `CanReadType` to return false then nothing gets parsed.

My question is, how can I make the code execute my overrides?

Comment: are you doing .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @a.white .net framework

Comment: @Alex Show a [mcve] that also includes the `WebApiConfig`. You are updating `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` yet the `Register` also has its own `HttpConfiguration config` being passed in. Chances are you are probably configuring the wrong one. One of the included links in the question is referring to asp.net-core which might have some differences.

Comment: @Alex One question I completely forgot to ask was **Why** you needed to change the parser? This lead me to wonder if this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Apart from changing the formatter, what is the end goal you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nikosi I am trying to discover if my application will be more efficient using a different JSON parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update how the formatter is registered

```
public static class WebApiConfig {

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

        // Other stuff...

        var jsonFormatter = new MyJsonFormatter();
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);

        //...
    }
}
```

Making sure the suggested syntax is followed in Startup or where ever the application is started.

```
// configure Web Api
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

There is also the process of content negotiation as suggested in the following article

[Supporting only JSON in ASP.NET Web API – the right way](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/)

Adapting it to your example, it would look like

```
public class JsonContentNegotiator : IContentNegotiator {
    MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;charset=utf-8");
    private readonly MyJsonFormatter _jsonFormatter;

    public JsonContentNegotiator(MyJsonFormatter formatter) {
        _jsonFormatter = formatter;
    }

    public ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters) {
        var result = new ContentNegotiationResult(_jsonFormatter, mediaType);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And registered against your `HttpConfiguration`

```
var jsonFormatter = new MyJsonFormatter();

config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);

//update content negotiation
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
```

Finally one piece of information to note is that the framework did tightly couple its JSON formatting to its own [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the <see cref="MediaTypeFormatter"/> to use for Json.
/// </summary>
public JsonMediaTypeFormatter JsonFormatter
{
    get { return Items.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().FirstOrDefault(); }
}
```

[Reference source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/MediaTypeFormatterCollection.cs#L57)

So depending on how much of the pipeline actually depends on the existence of an instance of `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, it would probably affect JSON related formatting.

If it is in fact a problem then my suggestion would be to derive from `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and override its members as needed.

```
public class MyJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter {

    //... removed for brevity

}
```

But that might bring with it, its own problems depending on what that base class is coupled to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your formatter in the startup config.

Comment: as far as I can see I have done that in the code in my question. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: When I tried your code, the formatted is hit everytime. However, your override of WriteToStreamAsync returns NULL. However breakpoints are being hit when GET is called.