# REST API service returning JSON, but Chrome showing double-encoded

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've written my first REST API service via my ASP.Net 4.5.2 Web Application, which accept JSON data (via POST) and returns JSON data.

When I call the service using PowerShell, the returned JSON is exactly as required, and using `$returnData | ConvertTo-Json` works as expected allowing access to the object...

```
 {"result":"ok"}
```

But when I call the service using [RestMan on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restman/ihgpcfpkpmdcghlnaofdmjkoemnlijdi?hl=en) the result appears to be double-encoded...

```
 "{\"result\":\"ok\"}"
```

I've also checked the developer tools in Chrome and the response tab shows this double-encoding, despite the response header containing `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`... which says to me this isn't a problem with RestMan, but my gut feeling is that it isn't an issue with Chrome either.

I've breakpointed on the final `Return` in the code, and the return string is definitely correct... it is not double-encoded.

I am not specifically setting the content type, .Net appears to be doing that for me, but I've tried setting it via `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType` and it doesn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: How exactly are you calling it in PowerShell? Maybe you are doing the same there - double-decoding it, once by PowerShell itself by using `Invoice-RestMethod` which already handles JSON for you (unlike `Invoke-WebRequest`) and once by another manual call to `ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: And I'd guess that you have the same issue on the server side - once it's already getting encoded automatically (since ASP.NET will automatically return the right format based on content negotiation, defaulting to JSON if no supported `Accept` header was sent), and maybe you additionally call `JsonSerializer.Serialize` and encode it a second time...

Comment: @CherryDT - I am indeed calling Invoke-RestMethod, but I'm under the impression that the `$returnData` is just a string, it's not an object

Comment: But that is the case because your API already returns a double-encoded object in the first place, so it's a string after the first auto-decoding.

Comment: I'm definitely not calling a 2nd Serialize... as I say, a breakpoint on the very final `return` shows that it is sending a correctly formed JSON string

Comment: I assume what happens is this: You have an object, you call `JsonSerializer.serialize` on it, turning it into a string. Then you return it, and ASP.NET JSON-encodes your string, resulting in a double-encoded object string. `Invoke-RestMethod` receives that string and decodes it, resulting in the original once-encoded string representation of the object, and you then call `ConvertFrom-Json` to resolve that second layer of encoding, getting back the original object.

Comment: *because your API already returns a double-encoded object in the first place* - ah, ok, that would make more sense

Comment: `I'm definitely not calling a 2nd Serialize` << from your perspective it'd be the 1st - which is apparent from your stating that it is `return`ing a string already! It is returning it to ASP.NET which will nicely encode it for you to send your value as JSON... Which already was JSON before, since you serialized it manually (unnecessarily). That's what I think

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT, that's really useful - I'll have a play, and get back you as soon as I can :-)

Comment: To sum up what I was trying to say: ASP.NET auto-encodes for you, and `Invoke-RestMethod` auto-decodes for you. So no need to manually encode or decode anything, otherwise it ends up getting encoded twice, which seems to be what happened here. You can just return an object. - I'm pretty convinced now that this is what's going on, so I'll turn it into an answer

Comment: You were absolutely spot on @CherryDT.  I assumed that I would have to return a string to ASP.Net... I had no ieda it would then encode that string.  Apologies for the follow up question (which I know is frowned upon in SO), but my issue now is that I was using Newtonsoft JSON to format it as needed (with null-properties ignored, etc)... do you have any idea how I can implement custom JSON formatting on the return object?

Comment: You should be able to use a custom `MediaTypeFormatter`. This article is a bit older but I think it still applies: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203063/web-api-change-json-parser (even though the OP says "parser" in the question, it seems to be about the formatter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you have two layers of JSON encoding: One done already by your tools (ASP.NET and `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell), and one done by yourself manually.

**Server side:**

1. You have an object containing a key `result` with value `ok`.
2. You call `JsonSerializer.Serialize` on that object, turning it into a string (a JSON string representing the object): `{"result":"ok"}`
3. You return this string from your request handler method.
4. ASP.NET takes your value and serializes it to JSON (*again!*), turning it into another string (a JSON string representing another JSON string representing the object): `"{\"result\":\"ok\"}"`
5. This double-encoded data is sent over the wire and returned in the HTTP request.

**Client side:**

1. PowerShell receives the raw string `"{\"result\":\"ok\"}"` from your server.
2. Since the content type is `application/json`, the `Invoke-RestMethod` function deserializes it for you, resulting in a new string value `{"result":"ok"}`, which is the original data returned from your request handler (a JSON string representing your object)
3. You call `ConvertFrom-Json` on that string, deserializing it a second time, resulting in an object containing a key `result` and value `ok`.

You see, if you'd just neither manually serialize nor manually deserialize your data but instead simply return an object and treat `$returnData` as object too (since your tools on both ends of the wire already take care of that for you anyway), you would end up with the same result, but you'd get the expected once-encoded JSON string over the wire instead of the twice-encoded one you see now.

Comment: Great write-up... you definitely deserve the credit on that. Thanks for the link to yet another useful Rick Strahl blog... I'll have a look and if I have more problem create a new question.  Thanks for your time and efforts,it's very much appreciated :-)